# Elastic failures logging

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm beginner in ElasticSearch. And my question is - How can we receive notifications about shards' failures like:

```
...    
"failures": [
                   {
                       "index": "some_index",
                       "reason": "RemoteTransportException[[Ocelot][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[some_index][3]: query[filtered(+status:act +isActive:T)->cache(_type:product)],from[0],size[1000],sort[<custom:\"name\": org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.BytesRefFieldComparatorSource@4b1221d>]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException: [FIELDDATA] Data too large, data for [name] would be larger than limit of [5133041664/4.7gb]]; nested: UncheckedExecutionException[org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException: [FIELDDATA] Data too large, data for [name] would be larger than limit of [5133041664/4.7gb]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[FIELDDATA] Data too large, data for [name] would be larger than limit of [5133041664/4.7gb]]; ",
                       "shard": 3,
                       "status": 500
                   }
],
...
```

with request body for quick investigation. **I'm interesting on notifications only with request's body.**

Do ElasticSearch have special tools for it?

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to store your ES logs in an index, similar to what you'd do with your application logs.

Then you have a few options

1. define a [percolator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html) that will help you detect new logs containing failures errors as they get indexed
2. use the official [Watcher plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/index.html) and define the conditions under which you'd like to be alerted
3. use Yelp's [ElastAlert](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert) which offer similar functionalities than Watcher (but is free)

Comment: Did this help? Do you need more info?